# Nagios frontend w/ API to change configuration?

Tags: monitoring, configuration, nagios, web-applications

My workplace used to use Monarch (bundled in Groundwork Community Edition). I built a custom CGI that would update the configuration when changes happen in our database of hosts (separate application).

Since Groundwork Community Edition is no longer supported and I can't find a standalone, new edition of Monarch, does anyone have suggestions for a free Nagios configuration frontend / config generator that has an API?

I've looked at nagiosql. It has no API, and the way it's written makes it hard to reuse its code from other PHP files that I may put in there to provide the API. At least Monarch has some modular code that can be reused.

Comment: I'm not sure Groundworks Community Edition ever really was "supported" -its status doesn't seem particularly different now (see http://www.groundworkopensource.com/2011/groundwork-monitor-community-edition-update/).  Other options exist, but if they are free, you will find the support is only as good as their open source developer base - again, this is no different from the way things were with Groundworks before.  If you are really looking for something "supported" then you probably need to pay, in which case Groundwork still seems a valid option.

Comment: @dunxd wasn't my decision, but then again we only need a Monarch replacement. I don't think we ever used what other parts of Groundwork added over plain Nagios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Icinga](http://www.icinga.org/) + [Icinga-Web](http://docs.icinga.org/1.2.0/en/icinga-web-intro.html) + [NConf](http://www.nconf.org/dokuwiki/doku.php)
Nconf has an API: [Link](http://www.nconf.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=nconf:help:documentation:api)

Icinga is a fairly recent Nagios-spark with lots of improvements.It does the job pretty well (I prefer it to Nagios because it has a single API you can use to get data and is 100% compatible with Nagios-plugins).

There is a video about Nagios VS Icinga that describes it pretty well: [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLqhXvGTazI) (It's by Icinga, so, approach with caution)

Comment: How's the API working for you? Have you tried it? NConf's database design is a bit unconventional (EAV design) so that's something I'm rather wary of.

Comment: Haven't used the API myself. Sorry.

Comment: If you haven't used the API yourself, why did you say you prefer it because it has the API?

Comment: I prefer the API of Icinga to get data from it (i.e. Jasper Reports can talk to it). Nconf also has an API (to make configuration changes) but I haven't used that one yet. How Icinga works: http://i.ytimg.com/vi/jLqhXvGTazI/0.jpg

Comment: 2024 UPDATE
I think it should be emphasized here that although Icinga EVOLVED from Nagios -- it is not the same product, does NOT share the same config structures anymore, so work needs to be done to port from old nagios configs into Icinga.
Also, icinga2 requires multiple setups (mysql, postgres, redis) so install is non trivial.  
  
That said, everything I can see so far suggests that it is a superior product in almost every way (except ease of setup).  
  
Check the related tickets if you don't want to take my word for it.
https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/icinga+nagios

Answer (score 2):

There is an [API written in perl](http://www.nconf.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=nconf:help:documentation:api&s%5B%5D=api) for NConf.

Comment: Copied from comment on TiZon's answer: How's the API working for you? Have you tried it? NConf's database design is a bit unconventional (EAV design) so that's something I'm rather wary of.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, haven't tried it. I just use NConf's web interface, which imho is the best one I've found yet.